# How to access string method inside function?

Tags: python

I have a program to be coded. I want to code a function that takes a word and an alphabet. Then the function will remove all the occurence of that alphabet in word and the return it.

I am coding it like this: -

```
str = "Sushant"

def removeLetter(word, letter):
    for j in range(0, len(word) + 1):
        if j == letter:
            word.replace(j, "")
    return word
print(removeLetter(str, "s"))
```

But it is giving me blank.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: `word.replace(j, "")` is `word = word.replace(j, "")`

Comment: You forgot to assign the result of each `replace` back to `word` (`word.replace` returns a *new* string, if you don't hold onto it, you lose it). Also, `j` will *never* equal `letter`; `j` is an `int`, `letter` is a `str`. Regardless, the whole loop is pointless; `replace` already removes all copies of the letter, so the entire body of your function could simplify to `return word.replace(letter, "")`, no need for a loop at all.

Comment: so how to compare for equality?

Comment: As others have said, the problem is that `.replace()` returns a _new_ string, which you aren't capturing, so `word` remains unchanged.  As such, I don't see how this code would ever return a blank.  It will return the original string "Sushant".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the for loop (as `replace` removes all instances of letter in word):

```
word = "Sushant"

def removeLetter(word, letter):
    return word.replace(letter, '')

removeLetter(word, "s")
```

Output:

```
'Suhant'
```

Comment: You also not need a method, just use replace?

Comment: Agreed, but OP said: 'I want to code a function ' so ...